# How to invert an existing master-detail relation within a mongodb document by using a query?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm just planning to switch from **Orders** collection structure to **Items** structure with a query.
Of course I'm able to to make it by iterating and with a few lines coding, but I'm sure there is an easier way to achieve it with a mongo query.

[image]

Each document in Orders collection can contain **a** User and **many** itemIds.
From this collection I would like to get an Items collection output with a query. What sort of aggregation/projection I need to use to get UserId**s** linked to **each** item **?**

Source, **Orders** collection

```
  {
    "UserId" : "Acme",
    "ItemIds" : [ 
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ]
   },.....
```

Destination, **Items** Collection

```
   {
    "ItemId" : 1,
    "UserIds" : [ 
        1, 
        3
    ]
   },....
```

*P.S. this is not a DB design question and the number of items in Orders and itemIds are finite. I made up them to explain the problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an aggregation pipeline with 3 stages:

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#unwind-aggregation) itemIDs
- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation) by itemID, [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html#push-aggregation) UserId into an array
- [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html#out-aggregation) to new collection

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Joe's method, I used this to 'invert' a parent-child relationship:

the Orders data looks like:

```json
[
  { userId: 1, itemIds: [5, 6, 7]},
  { userId: 2, itemIds: [7, 8, 9]},
  { userId: 1, itemIds: [4, 5, 6]},
  { userId: 3, itemIds: [5, 6, 7]}
]
```

Mongo Query:

```js
db.getCollection('Orders').aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$itemIds'},
  {$project: {userId: 1, itemIds: 1}},
  {$sort: {itemIds: 1, userId: 1}},
  {$group: { _id: "$itemIds", userIds: { $push : "$userId"} }},
  {$sort: { _id: 1 }}
])
```

*$sort is optional, of course*

the result should look like:

```json
[
  { itemId: 4: userIds: [1] },
  { itemId: 5: userIds: [1, 1, 3] },
  { itemId: 6: userIds: [1, 1, 3] },
  { itemId: 7: userIds: [1, 2, 3] },
  { itemId: 8: userIds: [2] },
  { itemId: 9: userIds: [2] },
]
```

If you want unique userIds

```js
{$group: { _id: "$itemIds", userIds: { $addToSet : "$userId"} }},
```